# Unable to print value of input field on keypress event

Tags: javascript, html, dom, enter

I am new to javascript and  have written a simple program where on mouse click and enter key press the value of input field will be printed in an ordered list. I am able to print the value using button click event, but not able to print it using keypress(enter key).

This is the error I am getting:

> [Violation] 'keypress' handler took 886ms

**JavaScript:**

```
let button=document.getElementById("enter");
let input=document.getElementById("ip");
let ol=document.getElementById("oList")

//variable button binds addEventListener method to a click event
//listening to click event and performning action onclick
button.addEventListener("click",function() {
    //if input's length is greater than 0 then create li, append the input to li and then append li with orderd list else will print nothing to add
    if(input.value.length>0) {
    //created a list tag to add results after user submits
        console.log(input.value);
        let li=document.createElement("li");
        //will append the newly create li with same text "testing"
        //createTextNode creates text
        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
        //the text will be added to the ordered list 
        ol.appendChild(li);
        //reason for input.value=""; is that it will reset the input field after submitting the value
        //if this is not given then input field won't be resetted everytime on input submit
        input.value="";
    }
    else {
        alert("nothing to add")
    }  
})

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if(input.value.length>0 && event.keycode==13) {
        let li=document.createElement("li");

        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));

        ol.appendChild(li);

        input.value="";
    }
    else {
        alert("nothing to enter");
    }

})
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Shopping list</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="list" id="1">
            <h1 id="2" >Shopping List</h1>
            <h2 id="3">Items:</h2>
            <input type="text" id="ip">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="enter">Add</button>
            <ol id="oList">
              <li>a</li>
            </ol>


      </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="shoppingList.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please update the question with relevant HTML......

Comment: So are you expecting a preview of what is being typed by using the `keypress` event or are you wanting to use that to enable/disable the enter button?

Comment: I want the result to be printed below it when enter key is pressed

Comment: So why not place the `input` and `button/submit` in a `form` and remove the forms default behaviour of submitting?

Comment: @SmitSanghvi Maybe this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/4hva5u68/) might be of some help?

Answer (score 0):

> The keypress event has been deprecated. You may want to use
>   beforeinput or keydown instead.

See this page for more information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress

If the issue does not get resolved by using `beforeinput` or `keydown` please share your html so we can help out further.